# Reasons to use ActionBarSherlock on API11+

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I planned to support Android 2.2+ with my app, and to make it look Holo I included ActionBarSherlock, but now I have to higher the limit to 3.0 because a couple of methods (e.g. PreferenceFragment) aren't available in lower APIs (and I do not want to rewrite all those methods for 2.2).
Are there advantages of ActionBarSherlock over the normal ActionBar(Compat) on API 11+? Should I remove the library to reduce the app's size or are there reasons why I should keep it?

Answer (score 1):

> because a couple of methods (e.g. PreferenceFragment) aren't available in lower APIs (and I do not want to rewrite all those methods for 2.2)

There are plenty of ways address this, while maintaining backwards compatibility. Not only did somebody else backport this (IIRC), but with a couple of lines of code you can support the older Android versions, as I demonstrate in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Prefs/FragmentsBC).

Note that I am not saying that you should not be raising your `android:minSdkVersion`, just that this specific reason is not an especially good reason. If your reason is "gee, is it really worth supporting a declining number of devices?", that's perfectly reasonable, particularly for new apps.

> Are there advantages of ActionBarSherlock over the normal ActionBar(Compat) on API 11+?

First, the AppCompat action bar would not change your preference issues.

Second, since [there are approximately zero devices running API Levels 11 through 14](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), if you are going to raise your `android:minSdkVersion`, go to 15. At that level, there is nothing the action bar backports will really add for you at this time.

If, however, you *do* decide to support API Level 11 as your minimum, there were a few things added to `ActionBar` in API Level 14, that ActionBarSherlock offers (and perhaps AppCompat, though I have not checked), that would be unavailable in the native action bar.

Comment: Thanks for that information. I know there were Preferences in pre-API 11, but those methods are deprecated, and I'd like not to support deprecated methods.
I didn't know there are that few devices running Honeycomb (it was a great and stylish OS in my opinion). Do you know which methods exactly have been implemented in API 14 that aren't in API 11? I currently use the v13 compat library because v4 and v7 have a bug in SectionsPagerAdapter.

Comment: @Lesik2008: "but those methods are deprecated, and I'd like not to support deprecated methods" -- Google marks methods and classes as deprecated as soon as they come up with something they like better. Some of your current code could become deprecated when Android 4.5 ships. Using deprecated methods on devices running API levels *where the deprecated methods were the correct answer* is frequently necessary to support older devices, for a wide range of definitions of "older".

Comment: @Lesik2008: "Do you know which methods exactly have been implemented in API 14 that aren't in API 11?" -- that information is in the JavaDocs for the `ActionBar` class. "I currently use the v13 compat library because v4 and v7 have a bug in SectionsPagerAdapter" -- there is no `SectionsPagerAdapter` in the Android SDK.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `FragmentPagerAdapter`, I am German and I couldn't remember the right term.

Comment: If anyone walks by here on this thread: Options like setHomeButtonEnabled and getThemedContext aren't available in API 11.